# Value copy issue in primefaces pickList component

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, clone, picklist

I am using primefaces picklist component, which is working fine

But the problem is i am using a List of DTO, after which is both Serializable and Clonable, the structure of the DTO is as shown below

```
public class SearchFieldMasterDTO implements Serializable, Clonable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private String id;
  private String fieldName;
  private String status;
  private String columnName;
  private List<String> fieldValues;
  private String fieldCode;
}
```

and the pickList component is as,

```
public class ActionClass {

  private DualListModel<SearchFieldMasterDTO> searchFields;
  List<SearchFieldMasterDTO> sourceSearchFields;
  List<SearchFieldMasterDTO> targetSearchFields;

  public init(){
    sourceSearchFields = service.getAllFields();
    targetSearchFields = new ArrayList<>();
    //here all the SearchFieldMasterDTO objects in the list having all the field values invluding  getFieldValues() (list of Sting) value
    searchFields = new DualListModel<> (sourceSearchFields,targetSearchFields);
 }

public void onTransfer() {
    sourceSearchFields = searchFields.getSource();
    targetSearchFields = searchFields.getTarget();
 // here only the getFieldValues() become null 
}
}
```

in the onTransfer ajax event i am getting the source and target list and i am setting into my field level List for further usage,

the problem is before creating  DualListModel , sourceList and targetList is having DTOs with all the values populated,

After transfer of single DTO from sourceList to targetList using primefaces pickList, i get the targetList using dualList.getTarget method and it is returning list with transferred object , but the only one value is becoming null

please help me,,, i thought pickList internally doing Object cloning so that it missed List of String field and i have overrided the clone method to deep clone all the values, but it not at all cloning the object i put breakpoint in clone method and i am sure its not calling the clone method, then where the Lis of String fieldValues property value alone is missing